# PDO store outputted array into variable

Tags: php, for-loop, pdo, fetchall

I am using PDO and I have the code outputting an array of my records when I echo the foreach loop. However I cannot figure out how to store this within a variable instead. If I replace `echo` with `$foo =` the variable is empty. My brain is stuck, I know it isn't hard but I cannot think what I need to change.

I would like all the rows to be stored within the variable e.g.
 `['2013-08-09','Heptageniidae',3],['2013-08-09','Ephemerellidae',2],`

Thanks

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM userrecords";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

//$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

```
echo json_encode( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ROW);


    //foreach ($data as $row): 
    // echo "['" . $row['eventdate'] . "','" . $row['scientificname'] . "'," .  $row['category_of_taxom'] . "],";
    //endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the right way of what are you doing

```
echo json_encode( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM) );
```

and here is what you were asking for

```
$foo = '';
foreach ($data as $row)
{
     $foo .= "['" . $row['eventdate'] . "','" 
          . $row['scientificname'] . "'," . $row['category_of_taxom'] . "],";
}
echo $foo;
```

which is WRONG.

Never create a JSON string manually.

Comment: I am not getting any output from this. I place it instead of everything after `$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);`

Comment: while you should place it after execute

Comment: I have edited the original question, still I have no result outputted? thanks for the info about using json too

Comment: Ok, it ways a typo if mine. But you ought have **error reporting** on.

Comment: Im using `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');`?

Comment: This doesn't help against parse errors like one happened in my code which I just found. these settings have to be set in php.ini

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your doing nothing wrong.
You might want to check $stmt->errorInfo(); for database problems, and you can use var_dump(); or print_r(); in php to check the contents of the array that was returned by the fetchAll() command.